# Prior to 1985 genetically modified genius and physically perfect baseball player

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find out what was the name of a science fiction book.  I provide the plot as I recall from over thirty years ago as best that I can.

Back in my college or pre-college days (aka prior to 1980), I read a book comprised of two stories or novellas telling about the development and fall of a genetically modified (to be a genius and physically perfect human) male (having wealthy parents who contributed the initial genetic unmodified material, had him well educated and trained, and made money available to their offspring) who pursued baseball to show the capability his physical skills and his mind.

The first part of the book has the male join an ailing baseball team that has "forever" held the lowest standings.  By his contribution alone, the team wins the World Series (the team does improve a bit but clearly wouldn't have won the Series without the "super male".)

The second half of the book is the more amazing part in hindsight:  the same male changes from being a player to the coach and owner of the team.  He uses statistics and motion study to have each player perform to his maximum potential and again had the team win the World Series.  All of this predicts the direction that baseball would take to be where it is today in applying these approaches.

Anyway, it turns out that the super male performed the items of the second half of the book so to show a woman, who considered him boorish and suboptimal, that he was more than a handsome athlete -- in the end, unreciprocated love destroyed the fellow.

Comment: Only thing this reminds me of is "Nobody Bothers Gus" by Algis Budrys- Gus is a superhuman, naturally evolved, who had a startingly great career in baseball that no-one remembers despite featuring int he record books. turns out, these evolved supers have a defense mechanism - if they show their powers, people simply don't recall seeing them or pass it off with a logical explanation. Budrys did several stories about these people- maybe one of those./ Gives you an author name anyway :)

Comment: I recall "Nobody Bothers Gus", which was a pretty good concept, but this isn't the novel (or novelette) that I was seeking.